# Show text if multiple cell values are True

Tags: excel, vba

I want a formula for column E3 depend on column A3,B3,C3 and D3. If multiple columns show yes or single column show yes I want show as below in pink. Need to combine shctin names which show "yes".Formula required for column E .End result shoul show as pink color.

[image: excel screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim x, y, z
    For x = 3 To 15
        For y = 1 To 4
            If UCase(Cells(x, y)) = "YES" Then
                z = z & "_" & Cells(2, y)
            End If
        Next y
        Cells(x, 5) = Right(z, Len(z) - 1)
        z = ""
    Next x
End Sub
```

### User Defined Function,the function code  belongs in a regular module.

Place this formula in E3 and drag down, 
=Get_It(A3:D3,2)

```
Function Get_It(a As Range, Return_Row As String)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim s As String
    For Each c In a.Cells
        If UCase(c) = "YES" Then
            s = s & "_" & Cells(Return_Row, c.Column)
        End If
    Next c
    Get_It = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)
End Function
```

---

[image]

Comment: i PASTE THIS IN TO VBA.SHOULD I CREATE A BUTTON?should I paste this code as a module?

Comment: I need to drag this formula down.How to modify this code for without pressing any button I need to drag this down.

Comment: if array formula of just formula is better .I have a huge range below.need to drag down.

Comment: Thanks Its working.What if I adjust htese column instead of A/B/C/D.How can I change this vba code?.Actual  column numbers are AE/AH/AK/AN.Please advise...

Answer (score 0):

There's another way using formulas. A little ugly but ok as a non-VBA alternative.

[image]